# Obtaining UTM Zone, Easting and Northing using Core Location in iOS7 and greater

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, utm

I am new to Objective-C, but have written a test app that shows me basic CLLocationManager info such as Heading, Course, Distance, Speed, Latitude and Longitude and the GPS data timeStamp info.  What I need is the corresponding UTM coordinates for a given NAD83 and/or WGS84 projection including the UTM Zone letter and numeric designator (e.g.  16-T) wherer I live in northern Indiana.  So, if I have :
LAT:  40.410250 
LON:  -86.127550

I need to convert or obtain through some (hopefully) existing method the UTM Zone, Easting and Northing coordinates of a given LAT/LON coordinate.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks...  Tim

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: How to convert MKMapPoint or CLLocationCoordinate2D to UTM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219775/ios-how-to-convert-mkmappoint-or-cllocationcoordinate2d-to-utm)  Specifically, check out the link to the JS page in the answer and look at their source code, which you could convert to obj-c, or one answer claims to have created a solution and posted to Github.

Comment: OK.  I will check it out.  I know in my Windows programming, I ended up purchasing a 3d party DLL to do this for me.  Don't think they have a Mac OSX versioj of it however.  Thanks

Comment: I haven't tested the solution that one of the answers says he put on GitHub, but it might be a good 3rd party library for iOS that could work for you.